# как воспроизвести звук во время клика в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

не работает `audio.PlayOneShot`

> **Ошибка:**
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object PlayerMove.Update () (at Assets/Script/PlayerMove.cs:29)

*Скрипт управления персонажем:*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Vector3 dir;

    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource audio;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        dir = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            speed=20;
            if (dir==Vector3.forward)
            {
                dir=Vector3.left;                   
                audio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
            }
            else
            {
                dir=Vector3.forward;
            }
        }

        float amoutToMove = speed*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(dir*amoutToMove);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вас не смущает выпадающая в консоли ошибка UnassignedReferenceException?
У вас всё правильно, просто вы забыли назначить источник звука - AudioSource audio.
Добавьте объекту, который должен издавать звук компонент AudioSource. Далее любым способом (через добавление public доступа переменной, атрибута [SerializeField] или GetComponent() на старте) передайте его в вашу переменную и будет вам воспроизведение звука.

Comment: `AudioSource` на объекте есть, также аудио файл поместил на `AudioClip` и на `impact` не работает

Comment: Ошибка, которую вы добавили в описание говорит о том, что у вас пустая ссылка на что-то, к чему вы обращаетесь.

Comment: @KillNoise, а если точнее, то ссылочная переменная audio указывает в пустоту. Прочитайте ещё раз мой ответ. Вы уверены, что переменной audio назначен AudioSource с вашего объекта? Добавьте в метод Start() строчку audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

Comment: Спасибо, исправил! нужно было `AudioSource audio;` присвоить `public` и на input `audio` тогда повесить сам `AudioSource`.

Comment: @KillNoise, да, это я и имел ввиду) а чтобы не нарушать инкапсуляцию (не давать доступ к этому полю извне) уберите public, а над переменной допишите [SerializeField] - результат будет тот же. И отметьте мой ответ правильным, если он вам помог с: